# Using Promise in method GET to fetch data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I have the code below to retrieve data from the URL (example). 
I can retrieve the data in Chrome fine but in Microsoft Edge, I cannot. 
How can I make this work for Edge?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
              <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" class="form-control">
              </select>
         </div>
    </div>
<script >
    function requestData() {

        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            let url = 'https://api.website.example';
            let req = new Request(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    "my-api-key": "MyAPIkeyCode"
                }
            });

            //fetch JSON Data and write it into console
            fetch(req)
                .then(async r => resolve(await r.text()))
                .catch(e => console.error('error...' + e));

        });

        return promise;

    }

requestData()
    .then(function(response) {
        var strInnerHTML = "";
        $.each(JSON.parse(response), function(index, value) {
            strInnerHTML += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });

        var firstIndex = '<option selected="true" disabled>Please Select</option>'

        document.getElementById('dropdown').innerHTML = firstIndex + strInnerHTML;


    })

</script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: which version of Edge? https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch

Comment: I had version 4... I just upgraded it and it works. @AlexanderMikhalchenko

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the way to solve browser compatibility issues